# Inserting a s string as var for a javascript function with ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to insert a graph into an ASP project, MVC pattern.
I defined by myself the string that is required in Json format, and it seems to work properly.
The string, defined by the controller is:

```
{ 
    labels: ['America','Europa', 'Global','Oceania'],
    datasets: [{
        data: [0.20, 0.20, 0.20, 0.40],
        backgroundColor: ['#a3aaf7','#89a8ff', '#01469b', '#0d1156'],
        hoverBackgroundColor: ['#beed9e', '#84ffbd', '#0afb00', '#058217']
     }] 
}
```

To insert the graph, using chart.js, obviously I need to pass this variable into the corresponding javascript function... I tried to use html helper (@html.displayfor) as well as the direct reference to the model variable (for example @Model.Tipologie_json):

```
 <script>
    var tipologia=new string(@Model.Tipologie_json);
    window.onload=function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("Tipologia").getContext("2d");
        var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, { type: 'pie', data: tipologia });
    }
 </script>
```

But the HTML is converted as :

```
var tipologia=new string({labels:[&#39;Equity&#39;],datasets:[{ data:[1.00000],backgroundColor:[&#39;#a3aaf7&#39;],hoverBackgroundColor:[&#39;#beed9e&#39;]}]});
```

So it converts the ' into its equivalent code and this make the computation of the chart to fail.
How can I pass a variable to HTML without any character conversion? many thanks

Comment: You could create a class with those arrays as properties, populate it and the use `JsonConvert.Serialise` (newtonsofts json nuget).  If you are doing it as a string, I don't think you would html encode the quotes like that

Comment: Yeah, just don't create a string, for one. You actually don't even need a custom class. You can define an anonymous object, and serialize that into JSON directly.

Comment: try this one `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tipologie_json))`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to insert a value directly into your javascript you can do this:

```
<script type="application/json" id="yourData">@Model.YourJson</script>
```

If the data in the model isn't already serialized as JSON you can do this:

```
<script type="application/json" id="yourData">
    @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.YourData, 
        new JsonSerializerSettings 
            { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }))
</script>
```

Or to serialize it in the controller (so that the model already contains JSON), you would set the string property of the model the same way:

```
model.SomeStringProperty = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    Model.YourData,
    new JsonSerializerSettings 
            { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
```

(I'm using settings that camelcase the JSON, but you could leave that out.)

Then to retrieve the data from your JavaScript:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("yourData").textContent);
```

Comment: Before I learned this I tried putting my JSON in `<input type='hidden' id='myData' value='...'>` Found out the hard way that it fails badly if the data contains apostrophes. I printed it out and hung it in my cubicle with a note to self not to do stupid things.